# How to set field required if depends this of choice of other field in the same form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am looking for the best solution of this task. I have simple class of form in forms.py:

```
class CategoriesForm(Form):
    RADIO_CHOICES = (
        ('c1', _("C1")),
        ('c2', _("C2")),
        ('c3', _("C3")),
        ('c4', _("C4")),
    )
    category = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(),choices=RADIO_CHOICES)

    subcategory_c1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(type="c1", public=True), empty_label="", label = "hhh")
    subcategory_c2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(type="c2", public=True), empty_label="", label = "rrr")
    subcategory_c3 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(type="c3", public=True), empty_label="", label = "aaa")
    subcategory_c4 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(type="c4", public=True), empty_label="", label = "eeee")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoriesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["subcategory_c1"].required = False
        self.fields["subcategory_c2"].required = False
        self.fields["subcategory_c3"].required = False
        self.fields["subcategory_c4"].required = False
```

This is only some draft.

The behavior of form should be following: When I will choose C1 category from radio select fields, subcategory_c1 should be required. When I will choose C2 category, subcategory_c2 should be required and select other subcategories fields (C1,C3,C4) should be optional. I hope my explanation is clear.

Draft of form in template:

```
field category (RadioSelect: C1, C2, C3, C4) <<required>>
field subcategory_c1 (Select: ---, a,b,c,d) <<required only if user checked C1>>
field subcategory_c2 (Select: ---, a,b,c,d) <<required only if user checked C2>>
field subcategory_c3 (Select: ---, a,b,c,d) <<required only if user checked C3>>
field subcategory_c4 (Select: ---, a,b,c,d) <<required only if user checked C4>>
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Hm, I am curious why nobody answered, is not possible to do this or so easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution requires a lot of things to do in case if new choices added.

Cleaner way is to make `subcategory` one field with all possible choices and filter them with JavaScript on client side. As a fallback for users without js there should be all possible well-categorized choices.

This solution makes sense since you need field with dynamically changing choices - looks like work for client-side magic. :)